# Reading mixed-format dates

Tags: r, date, readr

Where a column of dates contains two distinct formats, is there a way to parse both such that I get 2 rows of 2012-04-01 rather than the result below?

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
        date
      <date>
1 2012-04-01
2         NA

**Example Code**
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_csv("date\n01/04/12\n41000", col_types = cols_only("date" = col_date("%d/%m/%y")))
head(data)
```

Comment: You want `41000` parsed as a valid date?  Hm.

Comment: Look into `lubridate` and `parse_date_time`. Something like `parse_date_time(x, c("%Y-%m-%d`, %Y/%m/%d`), exact=TRUE)` might work. Otherwise, read your Date column in as character and `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: Dirk, yes, it's a format recognised by Excel as the number of days since the origin.  And Excel translates both the above as 1/4/12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`janitor::convert_to_date` handles a mix of Excel numeric values and date-formatted dates.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
data <- read_csv("date,text\n01/04/12,a\n41000,b\n02/02/13,c")

data %>%
      mutate(clean_date = convert_to_date(date,
                                          character_fun = lubridate::dmy))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   date     text  clean_date
#>   <chr>    <chr> <date>    
#> 1 01/04/12 a     2012-04-01
#> 2 41000    b     2012-04-01
#> 3 02/02/13 c     2013-02-02
```

*Self-promotion disclaimer: I authored this package.  But this function is built for precisely this use case so feels relevant to post here.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forcing a date data type while reading the data, you can try something like below:

```
data <- read_csv("date\n01/04/12\n41000")
data %>% mutate(date =ifelse(is.numeric(date), as.Date(date, origin = "1990-01-01"), date))
```

Comment: Thank you Shaojl7.  I'll give this a try this evening.

Comment: It happens to work with the two dates in my example as they translate to the same date, but if I add a third different date, I get the first date repeated.
data <- read_csv("date\n01/04/12\n41000\n02/05/13")

Comment: This set me on the right course, so thank you for that.  With a bit of tweaking I got it to work per the separate answer posted.